# Unable to find Visual Studio warning code

Tags: visual-studio, warnings, error-code, customtool

I need to suppress following warning in Visual Studio 2012:

> A custom tool 'AutoRunCustomTool' is associated with file '', but the output of the custom tool was not found in the project.  You may try re-running the custom tool by right-clicking on the file in the Solution Explorer and choosing Run Custom Tool.

The problem is that I can't find the code associated with that warning anywhere in the Web hence I am unable to suppress it in my project. Is there any way to find what the code is?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This appears to come from the **AutoRunCustomTool** in the Visual Studio gallery. There should be a "Run custom tool" property on each item in the project, changing the properties for the relevant file, or even uninstalling the **AutoRunCustomTool** should work. I note that the version 2.0.1 is dated 11/11/2013 and so is quite recent.

The error message quoted includes `file '', but` and so appears to have no file listed between the single primes.

See also http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ecb123bf-44bb-4ae3-91ee-a08fc1b9770e

Comment: Well, I think it does not matter which tool is associated with the file. I understand this warning and I just need to hide it from the list. 

there is no file listed between the single primes because I cut it, sorry for that

Comment: I believe that all the Visual Studio messages show their code when they are displayed. Messages from extensions such as items from the Visual Studio gallery are not part of Visual Studio and probably do not have a code that can be addressed by the normal suppression mechanisms. You could make a request to the author of the tool to provide a way of suppressing the warning, there are both review and Q&A sections on the gallery link in the answer.